# Play recap and ignored=1 in Ansible

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I am checking whether all services related to a *docker-compose.yml* are running on a system. The code snippet shown below.

```yaml
---
  - name: 
    shell: docker-compose ps -q "{{ item }}"
    register: result
    ignore_errors: yes
```

The code above works as expected. I have to ignore errors otherwise Ansible will not complete. The following result shows `ignored=1`

```
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
192.168.50.219             : ok=38   changed=12   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

If this completes successfully I want to run a subsequent playbook but don't know how to specify `ignored=1` correctly.

```yaml
---
  - name: 
    include_tasks: do_other_things.yml
    when: ignored is false
```

How do I get the result from `PLAY RECAP` into something I can test with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better idea than trying to cope with the error returned by `docker compose ps` when the container does not exist would be to use the purposed module: [`docker_container_info`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/docker_container_info_module.html) to achieve the same.

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - docker_container_info:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      register: containers
      loop: 
        - node1     # exists
        - node404   # does not exists

    - debug:
        msg: "`{{ item.item }}` is not started" 
      loop: "{{ containers.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.item }}"
      when: not item.exists
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [docker_container_info] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=node1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=node404)

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=node1) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=node404) => 
  msg: `node404` is not started
```